# Website doesnt scroll, no postition in css

Tags: css

My website (skinstuff.nl) will not scroll. Could someone help me. I really can not find out why.

There are no postions in my body or html.

Comment: When you decrease height of broweser to be lower than your website's height - it will scroll -.-

Comment: Well it scrolls fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to let it scroll horizontal dont set your `width:100%`

It doesn't scroll in height cause your content simply isn't high enough.